# How to add a string in between list in python

Tags: python, list

How to add a string in between list

firstlist = `['A', 'count(distinct(B)','max(C)', 'count(distinct(D)']`

Output list  `['A', 'count(distinct(B))','max(C)', 'count(distinct(D))']`

if the list is having distinct then one `)` has to added in the new list

Comment: `[i + ')' if 'distinct(' in i else i for i in firstlist]`

Comment: I have the feeling this is a really bad case of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular way:

```
first = ['A', 'count(distinct(B)','max(C)', 'count(distinct(D)']
out = []
for i in first:
    if "distinct(" in i: 
        out.append(i + ")")
    else:
        out.append(i)
```

List comprehension (my favourite):

```py
out = [i + ')' if 'distinct(' in i else i for i in first]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
firstlist = ['A', 'count(distinct(B)','max(C)', 'count(distinct(D)']
secondlist = []
for item in firstlist:
    if "distinct" in item:
        secondlist.append(item+")")
    else:
        secondlist.append(item)

print(secondlist)
```

OUTPUT :

```
['A', 'count(distinct(B))', 'max(C)', 'count(distinct(D))']
```

Answer (score 0):

use stack to store all unpaired '('. loop string, Encounter '(', stack append, Encounter ')' stack pop.

```
firstlist = ['A', 'count(distinct(B)','max(C)', 'count(distinct(D)']
secondlist =[]
for ele in firstlist:
    stack = []
    for char in ele:
        if char == '(':
            stack.append('(')
        if char == ')':
            stack.pop()

    for _ in stack:
        ele += ')'
    secondlist.append(ele)
print(secondlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings are immutable which means they cannot be modified.
So in order to to modify a string a new one has to be made.
Here are two ways to do it:

1. `firstlist[i] = firstlist[i] + ')'`
2. `firstlist[i] = ''.join(firstlist[i]+')')`

Example:

```
firstlist = ['A', 'count(distinct(B)','max(C)', 'count(distinct(D)']
Output = ['A', 'count(distinct(B))','max(C)', 'count(distinct(D))']

for i in range(len(firstlist)):
    if i == 1 or i == 3:
        firstlist[i] = firstlist[i] + ')'
        #firstlist[i] = ''.join(firstlist[i]+')')
assert firstlist == Output
```

You can also use list comprehension to add ) to all elements in the list:

```
listout = [elem + ')' for elem in firstlist]
```

Comment: I know it is not needed, just another way to do it

Comment: If you know it's not needed, why include it? Why not `''.join(c for c in list(map(str, firstlist[i] + ')')))`?

Comment: Works too, what I've mentioned is what came to my mind